# Converting a Portion of text to display on screen

Tags: coldfusion, bbcode

I am trying to insert a Portion of HTML Code to be converted in BBCode and insert into the Database, Somehow I am making some mistake

I am trying with the following case. If the Div tag which is of class "Code", everything written HTML inside that will make the tags to be safe to display on the screen. My Code will show what I am trying to do: Also, I want that my Other Text should not get effected, that portion can include html too, but that will be parsed automatically

Here is the snippet

```
<cfscript>
  function createCode(Text)
  {
    Text = Replace(Text, '&', '&amp;', 'ALL');
    Text = Replace(Text, '<', '[', 'ALL');
    Text = Replace(Text, '>', ']', 'ALL');
    Text = Replace(Text, Chr(13), '<br />', 'ALL');
    return Text;
  }
  </cfscript>
  <cfif arguments.structform.answer contains '<div class="code">'>
    <cfset getText = '<div class="code">([\s\S]*)</div>'>
    <cfset detectCode = #createCode(getText)#>
  </cfif>
  <cfdump var="#detectCode#" abort>
```

Comment: Are you saying that only html inside of `<div class="code">([\s\S]*)</div>` should be altered, and the rest left alone?

Comment: yes, The div which i specified should be altered only

Comment: `<cfset detectCode = jsoup.parse(arguments.structformat.answer).select('div.code').text() >`

Comment: Well what if i do not want to use jsoup, and do i need to ad some external library for that

Comment: To parse HTML you need a HTML parser. Without an actual reason for not using jSoup, it's hard to determine if other HTML parsers (Jericho/JTidy/TagSoup/etc) are worth suggesting.

Comment: What you need is to use one of CF's regexes to extract the text you need.  Right now you're just passing a literal string which looks like `([\s\S]*)`.  Instead use something like [REMatch](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REMatch) which will get you an array of matching strings:  `<cfset getText = REMatch('<div class="code">([\s\S]*)</div>', arguments.structform.answer)>`

Comment: A single regex is not a HTML parser. Doing it with that regex pattern will incorrectly match the entirety of content such as: `<div class="code">...</div>...<div class="somethingelse">...</div>`  - you can either keep making a regex more and more complicated until you basically end up with a badly written HTML parser, or you can skip the regex and just go straight to a properly written HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about displaying HTML code as code - not interpreted by the browser - and saving + reading it with a database , I'm not sure why're you're trying to reinvent the wheel.  ColdFusion has some built in functions like HTMLencode that will do the dirty work for you.

Comment: hi Allen, You are correct, i am doing like that, thanks for the suggestion, i will try this out too...